# Mask image with a triangle at the bottom

Tags: css, mask, css-shapes, clip-path

I'm trying to figure out how to best mask a div with an angular shape like so--if the top div in this case will be a background image, and both divs would be 100% width:

[image: Mask image with a triangle at the bottom]

I've seen lots of tutorials out there on how to mask an image with a circle shape, but none on how you would mask the border of a div like the red area. I know there must be a better way than doing this with bitmaps, but am at a loss.

Would it be best to do this with clip-path or SVG? I'm not all that concerned about older browsers, if the result is that they see the red/blue divs separated with a flat line. The entire red area will be a background image, so if old(er) browsers miss out on that angular border, so be it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `transform` (`skew` and `rotate`) to achieve this effect without the use of `clip-path` which has low support

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(lightblue, dodgerblue);
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:-50%;
  top:-50%;
  background:#D0021B;
  transform-origin: 0 100%; 
  transform:skewY(15deg);
}

.container:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:50%;
  top:-50%;
  background:#D0021B;
  transform-origin: 100% 0; 
  transform:skewY(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

For background images, you should apply `top:50%` on both the `pseudo-elements`

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/5NK0H1e.jpg");
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(lightblue,dodgerblue);
  transform: skew(10deg) rotate(10deg);
}
.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background:linear-gradient(lightblue,dodgerblue);
  transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: This is amazing, though it seems like it would limit me using a background image in the red area. I'll edit the original post to make that clear. Thank you for this--wondering if there's a solution given the use of a background image?

Comment: I really appreciate this answer--apologies for not having been clearer in my original post. This is great to know for other sections where I'm not using a background image. Thank you!

Comment: @hudsonian Edited my answer now you can apply background images too

Comment: Ah--that does work, and possibly has more browser support than using polygons? Are there any drawbacks to this method that you're aware of? I'm trying it at 100% width for a responsive design, and it appears to work great.

Thanks again!

Comment: you are welcome @hudsonian drawbacks, not anything that i know of comment here if you find anything

Answer (score 5):

If you plan on using the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property, you should note that [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) is very low at the moment as the [CSS Masking Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/) has the status of "candidate recomendation".

Therefore, you can make this shape pretty easily with this property using the `polygon()` value :

```css
.wrap {
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #4A90E2;
}
.wrap div {
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 90%, 50% 100%, 0% 90%);
          clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 90%, 50% 100%, 0% 90%);
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/5NK0H1e.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><div></div></div>
```